# Keyset does not exist - permissions should be OK

Tags: wcf, iis, permissions, certificate

I'm having an issue deploying a WCF service to IIS on Windows Server 2016.
The service needs a private key, which location is configured as follows:

```
<serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="..." />
```

I'm getting the famous error "Keyset does not exist", so I googled and doubled checked permissions etc.
The certificate is correctly placed in LocalMachine/Personal/Certificates. Primary Key export is allowed.

I granted primary key permissions to the APPPOOL identity and IIS_IUSRS.
I evenn tried granting full access to "Everyone".
I also tried running the application pool under my administrator account.

No luck.

I tried creating a small C# console application that reads the certificate, the primary key, and exports the primary key.
That works.

So I'm out of options now.
Any suggestions that might solve this?

Comment: If you run `certutil -store my` what do you see? If the certificate has private key associated there will be something like `Encryption test passed` or `Signature test passed`.

Comment: The certificate is there and it shows the message "Encryption test passed".

Comment: OK, then when you look at your IIS application pool. What identity does it run under (pool->advanced settings>identity)? It should be ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: That's the identity, yes.

Comment: Then the user that needs permissions should be `IIS APPPOOl\XYZ` where `XYZ` is the name of your pool. I set the permissions using `certlm.msc` with right click on certificate then All tasks->Manage private keys.

Comment: I'm aware about that. I also stated in my question that the app pool identity has permissions to the primary key :-)

Comment: Does your application use this AppPool? Is the certificate on some device like HSM or smartcard? Under what CSP was the certificate imported?

Comment: The application uses this app pool yes. The certificate is in the right location. Windows Cert Store, LocalMachine. I can retrieve it in my C# application, but not using WCF/IIS.

Comment: When you set apppool identity to local system or your account how does it behave?

Comment: It's the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Not possible. Local system should definitely work :) OK, lets try changing 32-bit/64-bit. Your console application is 32-bit? Try setting it to 64-bit. In the pool options there's also a property `Enable 32-bit applications` so WCF runs as 64-bit app. Try to enable it.

Comment: 32/64-bit didn't do any difference. However, i did solve the problem now. The application is running as a application of a parent site, but with it's own dedicated app pool. Granting private key permissions to the parent site's app pool, fixes the issue. It doesn't make any sense to me, but at least it works now...

Answer (score 0):

The application is running as a application of a parent site, but with it's own dedicated app pool. Granting private key permissions to the parent site's app pool, fixes the issue. It doesn't make any sense to me, but at least it works now...